# How to troubleshoot "Internal Server Error" in Azure MVC6 Beta8 app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC6 Beta8 app that works locally. However when I publish it to Azure and open a home page, it return Error 500 "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.".

I enable the logs, but can only see kudu logs and http raw logs

```
2015-10-16 07:38:48 RENT-A-BIKE GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=3c27af78-3874-4482-ac68-db29581070c1 80 - 112.207.250.32 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2490.71+Safari/537.36 .AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application=CfDJ8HSojZD46JRKpzcRvF66TcKzVHMrCLJRTTbz0MjK8rYaNUpfZzWwtz9EclfXXiMRUJ86IxNB_tWT5UhG03TptxP2tAXaedN0W1bQsMPhoeZR_OUrN5T0JeKZ8YAyqQkSfMmJo2rSphQFPfor7ztnbhs7vXaL0tYmsdflHAaRJH0nWs05vWuDfBkVnf7VofdoK5pICbz_QZ-HyNiH1dBzbl7CKvnzrpU7Erz4_hM4FPpAgY3hVRSuLuSYq8s9xnFNeLXI52u0DUU7GTwNYXZ946_wvjnIx706R6m4rh1c4__fLDNR6x2kPPHwWzKyftbhI3ETToJjAVtmNglY0WG9hCfZvZ_V_iCPWNmowfeU3YZ2Ux1lcDaHzr9o1o0T5ounqTzMqs_HzflN08-o7-xYF7BaqTOSjuScIWdpYDpXdzi7GAP3Hm7JPC3BG4A2GCoMjJpPDMDz6Aof9P0Td0EFB6XafDtduMewIZxf8-bGykUqoCgCb2i0dO21PFU-qkcg9kJ0LCm0kGdLERsEFLy4_a2X5vEBiyWIAlYu1JCb95l0FW87TcsMe1HwvsvubS4OkyIcKEo4UyX61AGPoRbf8OjXVvzYedG53mYdFVwsp2UARwmkGOqalp2ljGXYNCFtFkHc84ggj6XAvnnnvDCJDRAzABsNxm-b8mXtFEhgBKdzpS8Yn0egmHQNhDGP-hJy2hF-QJl8LnxjEpXg4yFtUaod54Y1_mopW11rkoWdz6aM4prIOf09TrG4NL4Y_1Ohgw;+_ga=GA1.3.68280290.1444933317;+ARRAffinity=e3c351936b5fcfb74e537a7dc58aebd6a3183747ae4ea853fe04b8e76e10ac5d - rent-a-bike.azurewebsites.net 500 19 183 466 1727 251
2015-10-16 07:38:48 RENT-A-BIKE GET /favicon.ico X-ARR-LOG-ID=5aaf9cc0-3594-4751-8571-197cc8465cef 80 - 112.207.250.32 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/46.0.2490.71+Safari/537.36 .AspNet.Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application=CfDJ8HSojZD46JRKpzcRvF66TcKzVHMrCLJRTTbz0MjK8rYaNUpfZzWwtz9EclfXXiMRUJ86IxNB_tWT5UhG03TptxP2tAXaedN0W1bQsMPhoeZR_OUrN5T0JeKZ8YAyqQkSfMmJo2rSphQFPfor7ztnbhs7vXaL0tYmsdflHAaRJH0nWs05vWuDfBkVnf7VofdoK5pICbz_QZ-HyNiH1dBzbl7CKvnzrpU7Erz4_hM4FPpAgY3hVRSuLuSYq8s9xnFNeLXI52u0DUU7GTwNYXZ946_wvjnIx706R6m4rh1c4__fLDNR6x2kPPHwWzKyftbhI3ETToJjAVtmNglY0WG9hCfZvZ_V_iCPWNmowfeU3YZ2Ux1lcDaHzr9o1o0T5ounqTzMqs_HzflN08-o7-xYF7BaqTOSjuScIWdpYDpXdzi7GAP3Hm7JPC3BG4A2GCoMjJpPDMDz6Aof9P0Td0EFB6XafDtduMewIZxf8-bGykUqoCgCb2i0dO21PFU-qkcg9kJ0LCm0kGdLERsEFLy4_a2X5vEBiyWIAlYu1JCb95l0FW87TcsMe1HwvsvubS4OkyIcKEo4UyX61AGPoRbf8OjXVvzYedG53mYdFVwsp2UARwmkGOqalp2ljGXYNCFtFkHc84ggj6XAvnnnvDCJDRAzABsNxm-b8mXtFEhgBKdzpS8Yn0egmHQNhDGP-hJy2hF-QJl8LnxjEpXg4yFtUaod54Y1_mopW11rkoWdz6aM4prIOf09TrG4NL4Y_1Ohgw;+_ga=GA1.3.68280290.1444933317;+ARRAffinity=e3c351936b5fcfb74e537a7dc58aebd6a3183747ae4ea853fe04b8e76e10ac5d http://rent-a-bike.azurewebsites.net/ rent-a-bike.azurewebsites.net 500 19 183 466 1696 31
```

I also tried to disable custom errors in web.config, but it doesn't work (and as I understand starting from Beta8 is not supposed to work).

How can I troubleshoot this problem to see an actual error that occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I enabled "Detailed Error Messages" is Azure web app configuration, I was able to see DetailedErrors folder in Log Files directory that had a number of .html files with error details.

Answer (score 0):

For that detailed errors begins appear in DetailedErrors folder in Log Files directory - restart your application in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

In `project.json` file, for the web command specify the environment parameter = development

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNET_ENV development",
  }
```

In the `Startup.cs` file, in Configure you should have:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }
```

This means that when you run in other hosting environment that development, the `Error page` will be displayed instead the `DeveloperExceptionPage`.